# Chrome extension accessing UWP app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, uwp, chrome-native-messaging, microsoft-edge-extension

We have chrome and FF extensions which works with a native messaging app. Recently we developed edge extension and a UWP app which works in the same way. Now the user has to install two separate native messaging apps if they want use any chrome/FF/Edge browsers.
My question is, is it possible for Chrome/FF extension talk to windows UWP app?

Comment: Does UWP apps support standard input and output? Not sure, but it should. If it does then it should be possible to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no. On Windows, both Chrome and Firefox use the registry to locate the native applications manifest, and Windows Store apps are forbidden from writing to the registry. (ref: [Prepare to package an app (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare)

If something changes (Store apps gain the ability to alter the registry, or Chrome and Firefox introduce an alternative way to locate the manifest), then it might be possible. Though likely not via the UWP app directly. UWP apps appear to support standard input and output, but the way they are run prevents access to it. It might however be possible to create an intermediary Win32 app that can communicate with the UWP app via the `AppService` and the browser extension via stdio.

Afterthought: Enpass Password Manager (win32) was ported to the Windows Store reportedly because of API issues, and has a browser extension for Chrome and Firefox. <strike>Might be worth asking them how they pulled it off.</strike> I did some more digging, and figured it out. `localhost` loopback, a custom url scheme, web sockets, and browser verifications is how they are doing it.  Not an ideal solution, but it seems to work.